# How can I get more Cubits without buying them?

Tags: facebook, chess-cube

I was playing [Chess Cube on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/ChessCube) and suddenly this popped up and I am not able to play any matches.

[image: screenshot]

Why is this happening? Is there way to continue playing? (Other than buying the cubits of course.)

Comment: RIP chesscube!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [What are ChessCube Cubits?](http://www.chesscube.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=33&sid=efa56d826e6635753289ff333b8f0ea8)

> **What is it?**
>
> Cubits are ChessCube’s virtual currency, which can be used to enter a ChessCube Tournament, play a wagered Chess match against other ChessCube users, or purchase items in the ChessCube store
>
> **How do I get Cubits?**
>
> - Directly purchasing Cubits using your Credit Card or Paypal account
> - Using your mobile phone to purchase Cubits through Zong
> - *Taking up and[sic] offer through Offerpal*
> - *Playing in ChessCube Tournaments and finishing in a Cubit prize position*
> - *Winning Cubits against another user in a Cubit Wager game*
> - ***Logging in daily***
> - *Playing in your first ChessCube Tournament*
> - ***Inviting your friends to ChessCube via email***

Emphasis mine — free options are italicized, the options I think are open to you are additionally bolded.

Answer (score 3):

Chesscube is not free --

You can play a few games for free every day, but after that you need to buy "Cubits".

Answer (score 2):

Don't play too many games if you don't have cubits or you don't want to buy them. Just play one a day for your daily bonus. You generate 100 cubits a day so 100*10 days nets you 1000 cubits.

Only play lots of games that you bet on if you know you are good.

Answer (score 1):

Make two accounts. Open both of them in different browsers. transfer cubits from one account to another by playing a match between them and then losing. you will easily get 200 cubits after 3-4 matches. repeat this process for different accounts.